# ¿Como paso al siguiente objeto de un Array?

Tags: javascript, array

Consigna: Se le pedirá al usuario que indique un día de la semana y se le deberá mostrar el día siguiente.

¿Como obtengo dicho resultado?

Este es el código:

```js
var dia = prompt("Indique un dia de la semana por favor");
var semana = ["lunes", "martes", "miercoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sabado", "domingo"] ;
var ddespues = dia[semana.length + 1]

document.write(ddespues);
```

Comment: Que resultado esperas si el usuario ingresa domingo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres hacerlo en solo 3 pasos puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
var dia = prompt("Indique un dia de la semana por favor");
var semana = ["lunes", "martes", "miercoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sabado", "domingo"] ;
var ddespues = semana[(1+semana.indexOf(dia))%7]

document.write(ddespues);
```

Para hallar el indice del día en el array `semana` puedes emplear `indexOf()`, una vez obtenido el indice puedes sumarle 1 y ya tienes el día siguiente.

Luego tienes el problema del domingo, ya que su indice es el ultimo (6) y si le sumas uno te enviará error, para resolverlo puedes usar un modulo (`%`), de ese modo al ingresar domingo te retornara a 0 (lunes).

y así queda la forma mas simplificada.

Comment: El mejor codigo. Simplificado y sencillo de leer. El codigo tiene que ser poesia, y he visto metodos con mas de 50 lineas. Quien lo lee eso? Hace falta hoy en dia, un entrenamiento en arquitectura de software que la profesion exige. Dificil, pero eso vale oro! Buen trabajo the-breaker

Comment: gracias @Gonzalo también debe tomarse en cuenta que en una respuesta de calidad es importante la explicación.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias ante todo por la detallada respuesta. ¿Que es lo que hace el modulo % en este caso?

Comment: @FernandoHildt el modulo `%` es un operador aritmético que devuelve el residuo de una división entera, por ejemplo si tienes 20÷6 el resultado entero es 3 y el residuo es 2 (6*3=18, 18+2=20), para mas información puedes revisar la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Aritm%C3%A9ticos#.25_.28modular.29)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres con la funcion `indexOf()` asi:

```js
var dia = prompt("Indique un dia de la semana por favor");
var semana = ["lunes", "martes", "miercoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sabado", "domingo"] ;
var index = semana.indexOf(dia);
if(index > -1 ) {
  if(index == 6) {
    document.write(semana[0]);
  } else { 
    document.write(semana[index+1]);
  }
} else {
  document.write("Ese dia no existe");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```js
let dia = prompt("Indique un dia de la semana por favor");
const semana = ["lunes", "martes", "miercoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sabado", "domingo"] ;
let diaNumero=semana.indexOf(dia)
if (diaNumero==semana.length-1) diaNumero=-1; 
let ddespues = semana[+diaNumero+1]

document.write(ddespues);
```

la linea con el condicional

```
if (diaNumero==semana.length-1) diaNumero=-1;
```

es para el caso en que el usuario introduzca *domingo*, el resultado sera *lunes*